# Pushing Content in HTML to top of the cell (vertically)

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

I am trying to push content in an HTML table to the top of the cell. I am using align to move it horizontally from left, right, and center, however, I am unsure how to align it vertically (top, middle, bottom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use valign at cell level i.e:

```
<td valign="top">Cybernate</td>
```

But I think valign is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td valign="top">foo</td>
```

The **valign** attribute is supported in all major browsers.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_valign) a live example.